# Pros n Cons of multiple links pointed to a single webpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

I'm designing an ASP.NET MVC Application in which I've constructed multiple Action methods for a single view with [ActionName("Name-Of-Action")] attribute  with each methods.

**E.g ViewName= Contact.aspx
controller Action  methods like :

```
[ActionName("Contact-us")]
```

Public ActionResult Contact_us()
{return view("Contact");}

.
.
`[ActionName("contact-now")]
Public ActionResult Contact_Now()
{return view("Contact");}`
.
.**

and so on...

I wish to make this site SEO Friendly, Can you please mention the pros and cons of calling a single webpage with different ActionMethods(URLs)  in terms of SEO Scenario.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with @naveen as specified, you could be penlised for duplicate content. If you really need to have different URLs for your content, you would need to use a canonical link tag so search engines know that the content is the same as the other page, and is not considered duplicate.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mydomain.com/contact.aspx" />
```

This is quite prevalent in shopping cart systems, whereby you *could* have a product in multiple categories, but you make all of the content essentially canonical to a single URL, e.g.

```
1. http://www.mydomain.com/products/jellyfish.aspx
2. http://www.mydomain.com/products/sealife/jellyfish.aspx <-- canonically the same as #1
```

Comment: That's absolutely what I was digging abt.

Thanks Naveen Anna, Matthew for the Reply.

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely affect you rankings adverslye if we sre talking not only about contact page.  Your site will be penalized for duplicate content.

A good approach will be to fix one as ur desired url and  Response.RedirectPermanent on the others. Stack Overflow deals with this issue like this.

Test for yourself by playing with our current url by deleting the slug or altering it. You will see 301(permanently redirected) issued in the console to the actual url.

Hope this helps.